# Making a timestamp from time calculated from elapsedRealtime and time gotten from server

Tags: android, validation, time

This is more of a "is this valid" type of question than "how do I do it", since my coworkers want a second opinion on it. We want to have an accurate timestamp of the time user takes a picture using our application, and the stamp should be something that our users can't influence. Since we want our application to work even though there's no internet connection, just asking the time from a server won't work.

I've currently done this so that the application asks a timestamp from the server, and at the same time takes note of what time Android's elapsedRealtime() clock has at that point. When user takes a picture, the software checks the elapsedRealtime() again, and then calculates the timespan between the two points of time saved from elapsedRealtime(). That timespan is then added to the timestamp gotten from the server, so that we'd have the time that represents the user's current time.

In the abstract level, does this sound like a valid solution that gives accurate time everytime? Are there other solutions to do this?

**EDIT:**
A requirement I forgot to mention: the pictures can't be lost even if the phone is turned off before sending them to the server, nor should the timestamp lose validity because of that.

Thanks in advance,
Xevas

Answer (score 0):

If it is absolutely imperative to get this time correct, you could start a timer when the user takes the first picture and then when you get internet access, check time on the server and calculate the time when the picture was taken by subtracting the time elapsed since the timer was turned on from the current time.

Comment: While this sound like a good idea, I don't think I can rely on it, since there's a chance that the user turns the phone off, thus initializing the timer. Since we want the pictures to be saved regardless of that (a requirement I forgot to mention; I'll add that to the question), that means we'd have to take possible shutdowns to account, instead of just getting the time once.

Comment: Maybe you can compliment your approach with mine - If there has been no shutdown since the picture was taken, use my approach, otherwise use yours. To make your approach more accurate, you could save the time from the server on the device and also note the difference between the device time and the actual time whenever the device comes online.